# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta en ADO.NET de un registro en especifico cuando no tiene llave primaria la tabla que deseo consultar?

Tags: ado.net

Estoy queriendo hacer una consulta para ver los datos específicos de un registro que esta en una tabla al que le doy clic, y este clic me tiene que aparecer  una ventana con todos los datos, sin embargo cuando le doy click a un registro especifico de la tabla me dice que el nombre de la columna 'acccj76fg' no es valido y para verificar si ese dato esta dentro de los registros de la tabla lo consulto en el server y efectivamente es el usuario que quiero ver sus datos pero no se por que no me devuelve los datos y me sale ese error,que estoy haciendo mal en mi consulta? no sé si estoy mal en mi `where`, lo único es que la tabla de donde saco los datos no tiene `id`, es decir, no tiene llave primaria.

No sé si eso tiene algo que ver, sin embargo estoy poniendo la primera columna de la tabla la cual es USUARIO, este es  mi consulta:

```
    void ConsultarUsuario(){
    sqlConnection conexion=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ejerciciosConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

     sqlCommand mySqlCommand=conexion.CreateCommand();
     conexion.Open();
     mySqlCommand.CommandText="SELECT USUARIO,rfc,importecredito,localidad FROM registros WHERE (USUARIO="+USUARIO+")";

     SqldataReader mySqlDatareader1=mySqlCommand.Executereader();

     while(mySqlDataReader1.read()){

     this.txtusuario=mySqlDataReader1["USUARIO"].toString;
     this.txtrfc=mySqlDataReader1["rfc"].toString;
     this.txtimportecredito=mySqlDataReader1["importecredito"].toString;
     this.txtlocalidad=mySqlDataReader1["localidad"].toString;
     }
     mySqlDataReader1.close();
     conexion.close();
     }
```

Asi es como esta mi codigo tambien intente poner `where USUARIO=USUARIO AND rfc=rfc;` y no me arroja nada,espero me puedan orientar en que es lo que estoy haciendo mal,el USUARIO no es numerico es varchar  ejemplo acccj76fg, no se si eso influye en las comillas de la consulta que estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de tantos intento di con la solucion para que me trajera todos los datos del registro seleccionado y fue por la comilla simple,asi es como me soluciono el problema que tenia

```
  where USUARIO='"+ USUARIO +"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes ser mas especifico a la hora de solicitarle la información al servidor ya que el servidor de base de datos te va a responder acorde a los criterios que tu le pongas.
En este caso al no haber una clave primaria deberás de colocar mas filtros(campos) para poder separar el registro de los demás similares quedandote asi un registro unico.
Aunque lo mas recomendable sera normalizar la base de datos.

Creo que deberías de implementar primero tus restricciones en tu base de datos para poder realizar tus querys o búsquedas ya que es algo muy ambiguo solicitar ahora que podrías realizar algo como `SELECT * FROM T_USUARIOS WHERE EMAIL='cadena' and NOMBRE='NOMBRE'`

Comment: ya intente utilizar el operador and para que el que los que tengan mismo  email y nombre lo traiga,pero me sigue arrojando un error,en otro modulo que es lo mismo tengo  where(Idsistema=1) and (IdUsuario="+IdUsuario+") para que todos los que tengan id 1 me traigan el usuario corrspondiente

Comment: podrias publicar tu consulta?? y de ser posible tu esquema de bd

Comment: actualice mas mi problematica y mi codigo por si gustas checarlo y orientarme que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu query, si la variable USUARIO no es numérica, se debe encerrar entre comillas simples ('). Esto te permite localizar el registro, independientemente de que el dato de búsqueda no sea llave primaria.

Es decir, la línea en la que armas la consulta quedaría del siguiente modo:

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText="SELECT USUARIO,rfc,importecredito,localidad FROM registros WHERE (USUARIO='"+USUARIO+"')";
```

Dos sugerencias

1. No es recomendable que las consultas se armen utilizando cadenas
   concatenadas. Pueden hacer que tu aplicación sea susceptible a
   ataques de inyección de SQL. En este caso, es mejor utilizar
   Procedimientos almacenados o bien consultas parametrizadas.
2. Es importante que las tablas de BD tengan una llave primaria. Esta
   siempre será una buena práctica de diseño.

Comment: Una pregunta, si el registro de un USUARIO es asi:AAAB2&333U,  ¿no es necesario convertirlo a string? aun asi como usted me lo explica puedo utilizar comillas simples (') para localizar el registro?, y gracias por los consejos,los empezare a corregir cuanto antes.